# How to use run_input.py to debug a user’s input?

Tags: debugging, integration

How can I debug a customer's input?

What is `run_input.py`?

How do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check which integrations version the customer currently has.

   - in MT: run `kubectl describe pods -n namespace | grep Image:` in watchdog
   - in ST: run `docker ps` in the user’s machine
2. Create a docker in the right environment (watchdog prod / dev is a good choice) - this command creates a docker with the integrations version you choose. The docker will delete itself when you exit it
   :

   `` docker run --rm -ti -e 'VAULT_GITHUB_TOKEN=<your github token>' -v `pwd`/out:/out docker-registry-2-i.alooma.io/integrations:<user's commit id> bash ``
3. Run the debugging script - (location - `scripts/run_input.py`) :

   - to see the possible flags of the script, run `pypy run_input.py -h`
   - execution example:
     `pypy run_input.py -e prod -d gadventures-1 -i f0dd88a4-ee3b-4414-aa90-c21b323bf473 -s e05fd -k .kafka_dump -r .result_dump`
   - if you don’t specify a state id, the script will run configure_tasks.